# Coldfusion Mura - URL changes when a page is edited - can this behavior be changed

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, mura

In Mura, when a page is edited, the URL changes in such a way that `/about-us/` becomes `/about-us1/` which then breaks any existing links to `/about-us/` unless we put in a 301 redirect.

`Mura:
    Core Version 5.6.4982 
    Site Version 5.6.4938`

Is there a setting in Mura that will stop this behavior from occurring so that `/about-us/` will remain as we intended? I've tried googling the topic but either there is not a setting or I'm not using the right search terms.

**UPDATED**
I contacted the user reporting the problem and here is their response (edited to protect the innocent):

---

Last week when this occurred, I was editing a pre-existing page.   However, it also happened today when I created a new page from the About Parent and the link to the "In the News" section didn’t work.

---

End of reply

Comment: It sounds like the original about-us was deleted and new one was added in. It is possible to un delete and edit?

Comment: No, it's occurring when the edits are published.

Comment: The only time I have seen that happen is when you attempt to create a page with the same name as an already existing page. That is not allowed so Mura simply appends a number to the new page. Are you sure there is not already an existing page with that name?

Comment: I'll go back to the user reporting the problem and ask.

Comment: Updated main body with response from user reporting the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@HPWD,

You can only have one page within a section of a site with the same URL title. For example:

- `/about-us/` ~ this would be a page located directly under the "Home" page.
- `/about-us1/` ~ if you see this, either there *is* or *was* another page under the "Home" page called "About Us".

I would suggest checking the Site Settings > "Trash Bin" if you don't see another page called "About Us" in the site tree. My guess would be that there *was* another page, and someone created a new one, and then deleted the original one.

Once you empty the Trash Bin, you can then update the `URL Title` field to remove the appended digit, and then save the content again.

Comment: I didn't think of checking trash. I'll do that when back at the computer. Is the user noticed that the URL will change or does Mira just do that behind the scenes unbeknownst to the user?

Comment: In the previous comment, "noticed" should have read "notified"

Comment: I found the Empty Trash can and have asked the user to empty that. Where do you find the `URL Title`? I've not seen that form field or if I've seen it, I'm not recalling.

Comment: I had to expand the "Additional Titles" section and there saw the URL Title as indicated above. I've updated the answer to reflect this additional step and would appreciate a peer review in order for the answer to be accepted.